# Fresh Ubuntu unable to find internet connections

Tags: networking, internet

I re-installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my partitioned Mac today after deleting the old Ubuntu partition. I am now unable to connect to the Internet wirelessly.
When I hover over the wireless icon in the menu bar, it tells me that no connections are found, then skips directly to stuff about VPN and whether networking is enabled. In my Network preference window, the only thing showing up has to do with proxies. 
I have reinstalled Ubuntu several times alongside my Mac OS Mavericks, and each time before this I was able to connect wirelessly.
I do not wish to use a wired connection or set up anything to do with VPN. What must I do to resolve this?
(Sorry if you don't really understand what I'm saying, this is my first time asking a question like this ^^;)
No proprietary drivers are being used.
lspci, as requested below, returns this:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:41a0] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. Dev. [106b:0117]
SATA controller [0106]: Marvell Technology Group LTD. 88SS9163 PCIe SSD Controller [164b:9183] (rev 14)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user but does your system require proprietary drivers ? If so did you check their menu ? (now hidden in the "system" part of the system properties). You can also type <i>iwconfig</i> in a terminal to see if your wireless card is known (just a start).

Comment: Let's start by identifying your wireless device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Then edit your question to add the result.

Comment: GhislainBugnicourt, no, it does not.
@chili555 I have added the results above.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this is the first instance of the device 14e4:41a0 that we have seen. The first suggestion I have is to try the proprietary driver. With a working internet connection, by ethernet or otherwise, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot. If the wireless is not working, check the log for clues:

```
sudo modprobe wl
dmesg | grep wl
```